# PHP assert code injection

Tags: php, injection, source-code, code-review

Not sure if in this case if it is possible to inject malicious code in $entityId and if it will be processed by php.

```
$entityId = $_GET["name"];

public function getMetaData($entityId) {
   assert('is_string($entityId)');
}
```

Note that using string as the assertion is deprecated since PHP 7.2.

[PHP assert](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.assert.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `assert` function will be called with one static parameter, the string `is_string($entityId)`.

Thanks to the usage of single quotes, `$entityId` won't be interpolated, so an attacker won't be able to execute any PHP code.