# PHP Code execution in function parameters and logical operators

Tags: php, code-execution

After wondering about [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/202348/php-assert-code-injection) and trying to better understanding, I tried the folowing code:

```
    is_string(3 and sleep(30));
```

Why PHP will execute code inside a parameter function (*sleep* in *is_string*) ?

And what is the role of [logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) in this case ?

```
Int as first in parameter for is_string:
is_string(3 and sleep(30));      // Exeuction of sleep()
is_string(3 or sleep(30));       // No-execution of sleep()
is_string(3 xor sleep(30))       // Execution of sleep()

String as first in parameter for is_string:
is_string("abc" and sleep(30));  // Execution of sleep()
is_string("abc" or sleep(30));  // No-execution of sleep()
is_string("abc" xor sleep(30));  // Execution of sleep()
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why not? A function parameter could be any expression or operator.  Does it make you wonder when we do `fopen($dir.'/file')`? This question doesn't belong to security@SO but rather to Stack Overflow and most likely has been answered there many times already. As to  why `or` made "no-execution", I wrote a nice article, that explains it in detail https://phpdelusions.net/articles/or_die

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP assert code injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/202348/php-assert-code-injection)

Comment: This is already answered in the question you linked: "usage of simple quotes, $entityId won't be interpolated" - in the absence of the single quotes the value inside the brackets will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

> Why PHP will execute code inside a parameter function (sleep in is_string) ?

When a function is called each parameter can be an expression. This is true for almost all languages and might be more obvious when you use something like `is_string("foo" . "bar")`.

> And what is the role of logical operators in this case ?

`and` just evaluates and combines the parts from left to right to get a result. `3 and sleep(30)` just means that it will treat `3` as a boolean and if this boolean is True (which it is in case if `3`) it will evaluate the right side of the `and` operator and thus execute `sleep(30)`.